# Access modal dialog from iframe not contained in the modal dialog? vbscript

Tags: iframe, vbscript, submit, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog displayed with ShowModalDialog, in it i have a form that is submitted to a iframe outside of the modal dialog. I want to close the modal dialog when the submit is finished. The problem is i cannot access the modal dialog from `window_onload` on the page that i submit.

in the modal dialog:

```
form.method = "POST"
form.target = "myiframe"
form.action = "save.asp"
form.submit
```

in save.asp

```
sub window_onload
    'Do stuff
    Here i want to tell the modal dialog to close itself
end sub
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can't. That's why it's called a *Modal* dialog box. In fact, a modal dialog box is a completely different window. There are much better, cross-platform alternatives using popup windows

Comment: That's unfortunate, is there someway i could make the submit wait until window_onload is finished? I have searched alot and think that's also not possible. The problem i have is related to an old product and i want to avoid rebuilding it. (cross-platform is not a concern, this is IE only)

Comment: Even in IE this is a very bad design. Almost everyone uses simulated popu dialogs using eg. jQueryUI's Dialog (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Even Microsoft's products

Comment: Yeah, most of it is bad design and built about 6 years before jquery initial release. But thanks for the answers, i will find another workaround.